# When using a Wacom Cintiq tablet and pen, can you pan while creating a feature using the freehand polygon plug-in in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing, pan, tablet

Is there a way to pause the free-hand tool in QGIS so that i can pan and move over the image and then continue my polygon?

Comment: With a mouse you can use the middle button, no idea how that maps to a tablet though I'm afraid

Comment: Thank you! That is still very helpful, I'll revert to that if nobody knows what to do with this tablet!

Comment: Is this because you've reached the edge of the screen?

Comment: @SamanthaHofmeyr I've done a lot with the Cintiq in the GIS space, and am friends with folks at WACOM if you need more assistance...

Comment: I'd like to see more. We can expose a middle-mouse button to you in a variety of ways. An ExpreesKey might be convenient, or the rocker switch on the pen. Mike Dana
Wacom

Comment: The spacebar do the same thing, if you can map keys to Wacom Cintiq or stylus buttons.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162420)

Comment: I was suggesting using the Wacom driver to assign the mouse function to a button on the pen or the device.  Not sure what's unanswered.  Exposing the sw interface through standard driver dashboard.

Comment: @MikeDana thank you yes I have now set one of the two buttons on the pen to middle click according to what worked for Ian above in the first comment, and that does the trick, I can now pan while drawing freehand if I click on the button :)

Comment: @Samantha Fantastic! Mike Dana

Comment: @MikeDana NICE!!!